# NullReference Exception in converting string to Char array

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception

It is showing `Null Reference Exception on line char[] myChar = read.ToCharArray();`.

I am unable to figure out. Please help

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StreamReader myReader = new StreamReader("TextFile1.txt");
        string read = "";

        while (read != null)
        {
            read = myReader.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(read);

        }

       char[] myChar = read.ToCharArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < myChar.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(myChar[i]);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(read);
        myReader.Close();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `while` loop right above that is exiting only after `read` is null, so of course `read.ToCharArray()` will give the exception.

Comment: at that line, *read* will be null, because of the condition in the while loop.

Comment: Maybe you could tell us what you want the code from `read.ToCharArray()` to achieve?

Comment: I need to match my string with a regular expression and for that reason i need to convert the string into char array to match every character in the string. can you help me out with any other logic?

Comment: You should describe what each part of your program is doing. For example when does this loop end:  `while (read != null)`  For example, step 1: Read the entire file and print it out. Step 2 I want to access the file again; I'll have to restart at the beginning of the file.

Answer (score 1):

The `read` should be `null` when the loop is finished and calling `ToCharArray` on null should give exception. you can put this statement in while loop. I believe you are trying to do some experimentation as you have already printed the string with `Console.WriteLine(read);`

```
while ((read = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
{      
    Console.WriteLine(read);
    char[] myChar = read.ToCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < myChar.Length; i++)        
        Console.WriteLine(myChar[i]);       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("TestFile.txt")) 
        {
            string line;
            // Read and display lines from the file until the end of 
            // the file is reached.
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine(line);
                sb.Append(line);
            }
        }

        var chars = sb.ToString().ToCharArray();
```

However, you should add each line into a stringbuilder and then convert it into char array. The thing is what you really want to do?